# Player does not move with moving platform when it is a dynamic RigidBody2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a moving platform that has RigidBody2D that is Kinematic. I have my player, who also have a RigidBody2D that is Dynamic. I parented the player manually onto the platform, when the platform moved I expected the player to move along with it. However, I see the transforms on the player getting updated but I don't actually see him moving in the game. Shouldn't the parenting forces my player to move with it? Also I notice if I change the player to Kinematic or turn off stimulated it works fine but that isn't an option since I still want my player to behave like a dynamic object.  I moved the platform by changing its velocity using the following code

```
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(5, 0);
```

Comment: that maybe down to your player controller, as this can overwrite whats going on

Comment: Having a dynamic Rigidbody on an object will override almost all parenting effects.  Either add friction to your platform or some form of physics joint that will affect the dynamic Rb directly.

Comment: @BugFinder: I can actually reproduce this without player object. I just tie a simple Rigidbody2D to a Kinematic one and it would not move with its parent at all

Comment: @Immersive adding friction to my platform didn't seem to help. Is there an easier way than to do my own physics to get moving platform to work? Moving platform should be pretty common in a 2D platformer game so I thought there would be some easier way

Comment: Can you show the code for the script(s) attached to the player? There might be something that prevents the player from moving per-update.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this script as a component to your player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform platform;
    public Vector2 offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        transform.position = platform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Then drag and drop the platform object on to the Platform property of the script component (in the Unity UI), and change the offset as you wish.

Let me know if it did the trick, or if there are any issues.